# How to return a nested document in an array

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents with a schema such as follows:

```
{
    "user_id": 123,
    "services":[
         {"name": "test",
          "data": ...
         },
         {"name": "test1",
          "data": ...
         },
         {"name": "test2",
          "data": ...
         }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get a service by name for a specific user_id returned as follows:

```
{"name": "test2",
    "data": ...
}
```

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around how to do this and seems an aggregation shouldn't be needed for something as simple as this but maybe I'm wrong. I'm sure a projection would work in a `find_one` statement but I'm not sure what to use. I'm using [Motor](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) btw not sure if that helps.

---

I have tried:

```
async def get_service_by_name(user_id, name):
    return await db.guilds.find_one({
        'user_id': 123,
        'services': {'$elemMatch': {'name': "test"}}},
        {'user_id: 0, 'services.$': 1}))
```

But this returns:

```
{"services":[{"name" : "test", "data" : "blah" }]}
```

And that's fine as it's close to what I want and all I'd need to do is:

```
service = await get_service_by_name(123, "test")
service = service['service'][0]
```

But is there a way to get the data back as just the service without an aggregation? And if not, then what should the aggregation look like?

**Edit**

I came up with an aggregation that does this but want to make sure there's no better way:

```
await db.guilds.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$services'},
    {'$match':{
        '_id': 123,
        'services.name': "test"}},
    {'$project': {
        '_id': 0,
        'name': '$services.name',
        'data': '$services.data'}}
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single document from `services` and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote it to root level:

```
db.guilds.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { user_id: 123, "services.name": "test" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$services"
    },
    {
        $match: { "services.name": "test" }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$services" }
    }
])
```

Comment: Oh wow, I came up with my own as well, see my edit. I like this way better. Although as far as performance which between yours and mine is better? *(I'm leaning toward yours although doesn't hurt to ask)*

Comment: Also, can the 2 match statements be combined in yours so it's one like I did? I'm not crazy good with aggregations

Comment: The sooner you filter out all the documents the better. So after first `$match` there should be only one document while in your aggregation you $unwind all of them and then run filtering - that should make the difference in terms of performance

Comment: Ahh, great I see. Thanks!

Comment: first match should also contain `"services.name": "test"` to filter out documents which do not contain `name: test` in its array field (if userId is not unique)

Comment: @Fanpark I assumed it's unique but added to the answer anyway, thank you !